# How to list acronyms without actually citing in the main document using acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro

I want some of the acronyms, listed in a file, to be listed while I don't want them to appear in the main document.  It is not possible using `\ac{}`, `\ac*{}` (Using `acro` package). How to do it? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I believe `\acuse` is what you're looking for.

Citing the manual section *Reset or Mark as Used, Test if Acronym Has Been Used*:

> `\acuse{<comma separated list of ids>}` This has the same effect as if
>   an acronym had been used twice, that is, further uses of `\ac` will
>   print the short form and the acronym will in any case be printed in
>   the list (as long as its class is not excluded).

There's also `\acuseall` which marks *all* defined acronyms as used.